# Using the same ClientSession to get multiple different urls

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-asyncio, aiohttp

Normally I code in requests so as a consequence I don't have much experience with aiohttp. But since requests is blocking I have to use aiohttp.

So what my code looks like in requests:

```
#Account gen code is here using requests 

r = requests.get(product_link)

watch_link = soup(r.text, "html.parser").find("div", {"id": "vi-atl-lnk"}).a["href"]

r = requests.get(watch_link)
r = requests.get(watch_link)
```

So what this does is that it goes to an Ebay listing and then uses BS4 to scrape the watch link that is in that listing's source code. It then uses GET request to add the listing to the watch list. There have to be 2 GET requests on the add to watch list link, otherwise it won't actually add it.

Well that was in requests but now I need to write this in aiohttp. The closest I got is this:

```
session = aiohttp.ClientSession()

async def main():
    #Account gen code is here using aiohttp and session 
    async with session.get(product_link) as resp:
         r = await resp.text()
         watch_link = soup(r, "html.parser").find("div", {"id": "vi-atl-lnk"}).a["href"]
    async with session.get(watch_link) as respp:   
         time.sleep(.1)
    async with session.get(watch_link) as resp:   
         time.sleep(.1)

 loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
 loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

I tried this and it ran for me, however it didn't add the item to the watch list. The code above this (not shown as it is not relevant to this problem AFAIK) ran perfectly and made the account. But it is not working when it comes to the watch list bit. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: I found the issue occured on `watch_link` , which is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
        async with session.post(link,data=payload,headers=headers) as resp:
            print("Created account with email " + random_catchall)
        async with session.get(product_link,headers=headers) as response:
            r = await response.text()
            watch_link = soup(r, "html.parser").find("div", {"id": "vi-atl-lnk"}).a["href"]

            print("Connected to product")

        async with session.get(watch_link,headers=headers) as respp:
            print("Sucessfully added to watchlist")
        async with session.get(watch_link,headers=headers) as respp:
            print("Added to watch list")


        await session.close()
```

This ended up working for me. No need for cookies or anything of that sort :)

Answer (score 2):

I try so many times and finally found it got an issue on cookies. And you need to change your code to `aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers)`. btw The truth may be in the cookies , where convert `;` to `\073`

> Not `aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers,cookies=cookies)`

There the code i sorted out.

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

product_link = ""

cookies = {"Cookie":"_ga=GA1.2.808...."}
headers = {"Connection": "keep-alive"}
headers.update(cookies)

async def main():
    #Account gen code is here using aiohttp and session 
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers) as sessions:

        async with sessions.get(product_link) as resp:
            r = await resp.text()
            watch_link = soup(r, "lxml").find("div", {"id": "vi-atl-lnk"}).a.get("href")
            print(watch_link)

        async with sessions.get(watch_link) as resp:
            pass

        async with sessions.get(watch_link) as resp:
            pass


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I'm confused. Why does aiohttp need the headers/cookies but requests doesn't?

Comment: No , you need cookies to let website confirm who you are , otherwise it hardly know which one watch list should he add in. (i tried again with requests and non-cookies , it failed)

Comment: @warkun5400 btw how did you get the result of  *requests doesn't* ?

Comment: I think the reason yours failed was because you didn't create an account and weren't signed into it before you tried to add to watch list

Comment: @warkun5400 it means you still need something to show who your are , that is cookies. I do not have login function so i have to add cookies by myself. So i think we did same , just differ on process

Comment: I assume the cookies will be different every login. So how can you get the cookies without doing it manually?

Comment: The better method to login is using `selenium` , because the post data is not easy to imitate. Btw it seems `extended discussions` now , SO is warning me @warkun5400